# Как извлечь подстроки по определённому разделителю с помощью регулярных выражений?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть строка, например `'POLSTOPLFKSTOPKOIUNSTOPSTOP1STOP'`.

С помощью регулярных выражений (модуль re в Python) нужно извлечь из этой строки следующие подстроки: `POL`, `LFK`, `KOIUN`, `1`, т.е. обозначить границы слова другим словом - `STOP`.

Я попробовал это сделать с помощью:

```
res = [_ for _ in re.findall(r'[^STOP]+', line)]
```

Но результат неверный.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my_str = 'POLSTOPLFKSTOPKOIUNSTOPSTOP1STOP'
```

Просто разбейте строку по 'STOP' и выберите непустые подстроки:

```
my_list = [w for w in my_str.split('STOP') if w]
```

в my_list будет:

```
>>> my_list
['POL', 'LFK', 'KOIUN', '1']
```

Answer (score 3):

Вам поможет `re.split()` или даже просто `split()`, если строка-разделитель простая.

```
>>> import re

>>> line = 'POLSTOPLFKSTOPKOIUNSTOPSTOP1STOP'

>>> re.split('STOP', line)
['POL', 'LFK', 'KOIUN', '', '1', '']

>>> line.split('STOP')
['POL', 'LFK', 'KOIUN', '', '1', '']
```

Затем пустые элементы отфильтровать любым удобным вам способом.